# Using List.js with two separate filters

Tags: javascript, listjs

I am using [List.js](http://www.listjs.com/) for an employee directory. I have a text input which I would like to filter **only** by the people's names. I have a dropdown of departments which I would like to filter **only** by department. Currently, the text input searches name **and** department.

Thoughts?

Comment: List comes with its own `filter` function. Are you using it? Where's the code?

Comment: I understand that it comes with a filter. And you can designate multiple filters. What I am trying to do is assign individual filters to specific inputs. So that text input only filters on name. And select menu only filters on department.

Comment: @ahitt6345 - Look at the demo on http://www.listjs.com/ .. the code is in the center (white) column and the example is in the right (black) column. In terms of this example, what I am trying to accomplish is to have the text field **only** filter based on the 'name' content. Such that typing 8 into the text field would not make "Jonny Strömberg" disappear, but rather would cause no change, as none of the names contain the number 8.